# Why does my downloaded MP3 files need to be unziped?

Tags: music, mp3, compression

I don't know why, but for some reason, the google music don't play them directly, everytime, it opens winRAR on my Nexus 5X then plays it.

This only happens to the mp3 that I downloaded from internet, ie. sites like: youtube to mp3, clipconverter.cc

I am trying to make a playlist of youtube podcasts, and for somereason, I need to click the file, it opens winrar, then plays it, and if I uninstall winrar, then i can't play the music...

How do I solve this?  I quite like the current music player native to my nexus 5x, and it's not working out after a few weeks of trying....

Comment: Because the mp3 files you downloaded are zipped, (or you have a messed up file association (default app for the file type) somewhere). Do you use ES File Explorer or some such app?

Answer (score 1):

Right, when we download the mp3 files using websites like [youtube to mp3](http://feedsyouneed.com/best-free-youtube-to-mp3-converter/) etc etc they provide us mp3 songs in zip files. so in order to avoid it, you need to follow few below steps.

first click on **SETTING**

then go for **DOWNLOAD SETTINGS**

then at the end there is an option names **MORE OPTIONS**

Just check the **DOWNLOAD DIRECTLY**

that's it, it will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the music you are downloading is being delivered to you as a compressed file--that is likely why winRAR opens up before you are able to listen to it! WinRAR is able to unzip files on the fly so that you can use the file without having to actually extract them first.

To stop this from happening, extract the music and save it on your phone. (then go ahead and delete the original archive to keep things tidy, if you wish)

Are you able to tell us what the file extension of those files are that open in winRAR?